# Why isn't local transform orientation doing anything?

Tags: transforms

Very easy problem to explain: the local transform orientation is not doing anything. Which is a problem because I want the bottle to move exactly down a certain axis. Tapping the axis twice does not do anything either.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It does nothing? no transform at all, and you didn't lock the transforms, in any way? can you share the file (or a part of it) ie by http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? by the way that global/local setting is for the "3d manipulator" only, imho.

Comment: Do you mean there's no difference with global axis or you can't move/rotate/scale along local axis?

Comment: Did you try resetting the objects scale and rotation?  shortcut: CTRL + A

Comment: global and local are the same if you rotate the mesh in 'edit mode', but they are different if you rotate the mesh in 'object mode'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have applied transformations using CTRL+A.
If so, you can try entering **Edit Mode** and switch the **Transformation Orientation** to *Normal*.

Another option is using the model's edge and move the model's geometry by its normals, then reset the origin - like this:

[image: grab using model's edge normals]

Comment: Yes thank you this solves the problem perfectly. Just to add to your answer for anyone else. If you don't have a plane or edge that is perfectly flat (like in his example, say for instance a spear tip) you can still select the vert that is at the point of the object. Then using the Normal orientation you should still be able to move it in the desired axis.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try, much easier, is to pres R for rotation and than Z two times. The second time around Blender offers you to rotate around normal orientated axis automatically. But that doesnt work anymore after applying rotation to your mesh since that resets orientation to global.

Cheers!

Comment: Using normal orientation works after applying rotation as well as applying doesn't change normals orientation.

Comment: This is exactly what it does: it sets current rotation of the object equivalent to 0. This is the whole purpose of applying rotation. Try it for yourself.

Comment: I tried to do what I know pretty good for the ~200-th time and saw what I saw every time before - [that orienation of the normals does NOT change after applying rotation and applying does NOT prevent from rotation face around normal-oriented vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0AV1.gif) since applying rotation has nothing to do with normal orientation of the face. Either you meant Local transform orientation or you didn't try to use transform orientations.

Comment: Yes indeed. You cannot change normal orientation of the face as it can only be one way. But Iam talking about **objects** here since the original question reffers to why the whole bottle is the way it is and not one single face on it.